# Can a java midlet get details of an unknown mobile

Tags: mobile, java-me, midp, midlet

I have China made iphone replica. JVM has pre-installed in it. I want to know the specifications of this mobile like Operating System[OS],Processor [Speed & Brand],RAM etc. Is it possible with a j2me midlet?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Depending on the JVM installed, it's not assured that these commands will give you the correct answer. For example, I've been working with a Motorolla Q11 that's not even capable of cheking that it has a QWERTY keyboard, while other phones can. So, try it, if it works, thats ok, but dont count on that. And if you are asking for the commands, sorry, I dont know all of them, but I think you can easily google them.

Comment: Basically i am trying to write a j2me code and compile it into jar, so that it can be executed on this device. This device only accepts a jar file, i cannot execute any command on it.

Comment: Yes, if I understood well, you want to discover these infos using Java commands inside the program, at least that's what i mean with my answer. J2ME provides some calls to discover the device settings, however, as I said, they can be wrong.